# The tag <text> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, styled-components, vite

### Problem

I just tried to build a component via styled components on vite. But, When I try to use text from styled components, It throws an error on console:

```
Warning: The tag <text> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
    at text
    at O2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=b320d886:1423:6)
    at TextView (http://localhost:5173/src/components/TextView/index.jsx?t=1678354528314:18:3)
    at Header
    at App
printWarning                @   react-dom.development.js:86
error                       @   react-dom.development.js:60
createElement               @   react-dom.development.js:9816
createInstance              @   react-dom.development.js:10941
completeWork                @   react-dom.development.js:22187
completeUnitOfWork          @   react-dom.development.js:26596
performUnitOfWork           @   react-dom.development.js:26568
workLoopSync                @   react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync              @   react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @   react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop                    @   scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork                   @   scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline    @   scheduler.development.js:533
```

### Code

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
// import variablesBreakpoints from '../../helpers/variablesBreakpoints';

function TextView({ children, color, fontSize, fontWeight }) {
  const StyledText = styled.text`
    color: ${color};
    font-size: ${fontSize};
    font-weight: ${fontWeight};
  `;

  return <StyledText>{children}</StyledText>;
}

TextView.defaultProps = {
  color: '#fff',
  fontSize: '1em',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
};

export default TextView;
```

### Note

1. I didn't convert with uppercase because it does automatically.
2. I done a research and I saw plugins about that.

Comment: <text /> is not a standard html tag. Use `styled.p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`styled.text`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/v5.3.8/packages/styled-components/src/utils/domElements.js#L140) exists, it is supposed to be used only in [SVG context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text).

If you want to use it somewhere else, as suggested by Undo in the question comment, use `<p>` or `<span>` tags instead (so respectively `styled.p` or `styled.span`).